# Identify feature tool display

Tags: qgis

I have a minor but annoying issue with the Identify Feature tool.

When using the Identify Feature tool, the menu in the side bar comes up as fully expanded - I can see a lot of detail that I don't need: the dropdown menu "(Derived)" is automatically expanded. This means that on a small screen I have to minimise that dropdown menu to see the info that I want to see straight away, which is the "(Actions)" menu. The information used to appear with the "(Actions)" dropdown menu expanded, and "(Derived)" minimised.

Can anyone tell me how to change it back, so that the default is my being able to see the Actions, but not Derived?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[image]

Click the button in the red circle.